# Angularjs: passing an object params to state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state

I'd like to pass an object to a state. Here is how I did it:

```
.state('options', {
    url: "/options?current_task",
    views: {
      "middle": {
        templateUrl: "/games/options.html"
      }
    }
```

And here is how I call it:

```
$state.go("options", {current_task: task});
```

But instead of passing an object, it passed a String "Object Object"
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Question not clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter you pass in the URL is always a string. You could pass multiple strings and combine them again to an object.

```
.state('options', {
    url: "/options?current_task_1&current_task2",
    views: {
      "middle": {
        templateUrl: "/games/options.html"
  }
}
```